# Current nth:child of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way to find out what the `nth:child` of the `div` I click on div?

```js
$('#divStatus div').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).parents().eq())
})
```

```css
#divStatus div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divStatus">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using jQuery's [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) function. `index` is 0-based, whereas `:nth-child` is 1-based, so you have to allow for that.

```js
$('#divStatus div').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).index() + 1);
})
```

```css
#divStatus div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divStatus">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.

Answer (score 1):

use `index()` function for this.

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/mvsq5ssL/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="divStatus">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#divStatus div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

JS code :

```
 $('#divStatus div').on('click', function() {
 var nth = $(this).index() + 1;
 console.log(nth)
})
```

`index()` starts from `0` , in your case you need it to start from `1` ( `nth-child(1)` ) that's why you add 1 to `index()`

read more about [index() here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: The OP gave a nice, on-site runnable example. Why hide the runnable part of the answer off-site?

Comment: sorry. edited the answer with the full code. not really sure how to use code snippet ( never used it ) , that's why i use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.index()` function to get index of current clicked div:

Index will be zero based, so you need to add +1 to it for getting its proper index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divStatus div').click(function() {
      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      console.log(index);
  });
});
```

```css
#divStatus div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divStatus">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```